# JQuery selector for highlighted text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know how to select Highlighted text using JQuery selector.
For example, to select elements with a class, you use `.class`, for IDs, you use `#id`.

What do I use for highlighted text so that I can (for example) hide them:

`$("Highlighted text").hide();`

What is the highlighted text selector, and how to hide highlighted text?

Comment: highlighted text should have a class use that, show the code how is your html is highlighted

Comment: By "highlighted text," do you mean the text the user has selected on the page or something else? If it's the former, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text If it's the latter, please clarify exactly what you're trying to target.

Comment: yes I mean the text a user selects on a page

Comment: Then the question I linked in my comment is what you're looking for - no need for jQuery here.

Comment: +1 for good question and added `and how to hide highlighted text?` as op needs this.

Answer (score 3):

This is one your are looking for i believe:

```
text = window.getSelection().toString();
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/5gqrfhms/)

### Hide selected/highlighted text javascript

You have to get parent of Element from DOM:

```
function getSelectionParentElement() {
    var parentEl = null, sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            parentEl = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
            if (parentEl.nodeType != 1) {
                parentEl = parentEl.parentNode;
            }
        }
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        parentEl = sel.createRange().parentElement();
    }
    return parentEl;
}
```

## [NEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/04L1gr3t/4/)

### Update

Fixed demo to hide text we have to find `startOffset`

```
function getStartOffset() {
    var sel = document.selection, range, rect;
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    if (sel) {
        if (sel.type != "Control") {
            range = sel.createRange();
            range.collapse(true);
        }
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            if (range.getClientRects) {
                range.collapse(true);
            }
        }
    }
    return range.startOffset;
}
```

## [Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/04L1gr3t/7/)

Comment: okay, how do I hide this selected text on a click of a button?

Comment: oops one notice! this works but it hides the first instance of the text similar to the highlighted text.
for example, if I have a text:
"four months and four days" and I highlighted the "four" before "days", and clicked "hide", the "four" before "monthss" will be hidden not the "four" before "days". can you please fix this?

Comment: Make a fiddle @Othuna. Sure i'll contribute

Comment: @Othuna Please set this answer as accepted answer that others can use this useful question and answer. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($("idDiv").html().contains('Highlighted text')==true)
 {
   var a=$("#idDiv").html();
   a=a.replace("Highlighted text","<p id='highlightedtext'>Highlighted text</p>");
   $("#idDiv").html(a);
   $("#highlightedtext").hide();
  }
```

The above code check the highlighted text from the div and if it found it set that text in p tag with id and using that id you can hide it

Comment: You provide code, but you don't provide an explanation as to why this works. Please add an explanation to aid the OP and future readers.